# jQuery + Javascript - accessing object fields in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm not into JavaScript OOP, so I've made an object with some fields which contains some functions to invoke.

```
var test = {
    questions: [],

    addQuestion: function(questionTitle, possibleAnwsers)
    {
        // not really important
    },

    appendQuestionToHTML: function(question)
    {
        // not really important
    },

    makeQuestionFieldsEditable: function($questionNode)
    {
        $questionNode.find(".questionTitle").first(function(){this.changeTextOnClick($(this));});
        $questionNode.find(".questionChoice").each(function(){this.changeTextOnClick($(this));});
    },

    changeTextOnClick: function($spanElement)
    {
        // not really important
    }
};
```

Following object in makeQuestionFieldsEditable() function looks for ".questionTitle"-class node and all of ".questionChoice"-class nodes invoke another function for them.
The problem is that using this in anonymous function references to itself, not function saved on field changeTextOnClick.
Javascript/JQuery wants to invoke this function on HTMLDivElement, which doesn't exists.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can do the trick using a reference to your `this` variable :

```
makeQuestionFieldsEditable: function($questionNode)
{
    var that = this;
    $questionNode.find(".questionTitle").first(function(){that.changeTextOnClick($(this));});
    $questionNode.find(".questionChoice").each(function(){that.changeTextOnClick($(this));});
},
```

Comment: Sorry, it's too simple, I cannot accept your anwser. Just kidding, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to do is change 'this' to 'test' (the variable you have assigned this object to).

Comment: an object should never have to refer to itself by the name of a variable referencing it.

Comment: This one also works, but I don't think if it's right way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Visher it works, but it's a nasty hack.  If `test` gets renamed then the contents of the object have to change too.  It also prevents more than one instance of the object from existing.

Comment: I object to the phrase "nasty hack" in reference to calling a singleton by its name. If it were declared as a class rather than a singleton, that's another story.